# my global variable can not see in meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, reactjs

I have created a variable named `myVar` in a js file. The js file is located in the client folder of my meteor app.

I have checked that the js file has already loaded because the `console.log('...')` has printed but I can not see `myVar` when I want to call it.

The error message content is :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: floaty is not defined

Comment: Where's your code? Why are you seeing `floaty is not defined` when you're saying it's named `myVar`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please provide us with some code so we can see what you're doing and find the problem.

Comment: you may be facing error somewhere else. May be your myVar is still accessible but you are trying to access floaty somewhere when its not defined at all

Comment: sorry, my variable name is floaty, not myVar
in js file floaty is declared as following
var floaty = floaty||{}
....

Answer (score 0):

I just run into this problem right now.  Try replacing 'var floaty' with 'window.floaty'